# Ошибка при переносе MySQL

Tags: wordpress

Всем добра !  Переношу сайт на WordPress на другой хост и домен, поменял в конфиге все, в бД тоже , но сайт не работает. И при импорте базы выдает вот такую ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Поискал в инете, пробовал делать замену INSERT INTO на PRIMERY INTO,как пишут на сайтах, но все равно ни чего не помогает. Может кто знает как вылечить болячку ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку